# How to move button creation code into style

Tags: wpf

Looking to shift my button creation code into a style... but not entirely sure of how to define some elements (like height which is dependent on grid height) and mouse event triggers..

Current code is as follows:

```
        button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        button.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        button.Name = buttonName;
        button.Margin = new Thickness(2);
        button.Padding = new Thickness(2);

        // We want the ellipse to have the same height and width, so let's calculate
        // the smallest of the two calculated measurements and then apply that to both of them
        var potentialHeight = (wGrid.Height / wGrid.Columns) - (button.Margin.Top * 2);
        var potentialWidth = (wGrid.Width / wGrid.Rows) - (button.Margin.Left * 2);
        button.Height = button.Width = (potentialHeight < potentialWidth) ? potentialHeight : potentialWidth;

        button.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, column);
        button.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, row);
        button.MouseEnter += Button_MouseEnter;
        button.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += PreviewButton_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        button.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += PreviewButton_MouseLeftButtonUp;
        button.MouseLeave += Button_MouseLeave;

        var style = Utilities.ResourceDictionary["WButton"] as Style;
        button.Style = style;
        SetButtonBackground(button);
```

Comment: What is the final outcome supposed to be? A Grid of square Buttons that each perform the same action? Without more context it's hard to tell what you should actually do.

Comment: Yes is the answer to your question.

Comment: Use an ItemsControl with the Grid in its ItemsPanel, and the Button in its ItemTemplate. There would also be an ItemContainerStyle for binding the Grid.Row and Grid.Colum properties. The ItemsSource property would be bound to a collection of data items with all necessary data fo the individual Buttons.

Comment: Could you whip up a really bare boned example Clemens? I get told a similar thing but I can't quite piece together how the ItemContainerStyle, Panel and source all come together :\

Comment: Sorry, there's not enough context in your question write any useful answer.

Comment: No worries.....

Comment: Glad you're not worried then :D There are reasons I can't give too much info into the UI - have a good day (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Button">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource WButton}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="Button_MouseEnter"/>
                        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="PreviewButton_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="PreviewButton_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="Button_MouseLeave"/>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: The Grid.Column and Grid.Row Bindings won't work that way. You would have to move them into an ItemContainerStyle.

Comment: Thanks @Neil B - a lot of that makes sense for me to build on :)